# Rails: when using params, why do my route parameters not show when using require with permit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sent with request:

```
{ 
  character: {
    name: 'Tommy'
  } 
}
```

Routes:

```
resources :campaigns, only: [:index, :create, :destroy] do
  resources :characters, only: [:create]
end
```

with rails routes command:

```
POST   /api/campaigns/:campaign_id/characters(.:format)
```

Invoking params:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"character"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Tommy"} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"api/characters", "action"=>"create", "campaign_id"=>"2366"} permitted: false>
```

With require:

```
def character_params
  params.require(:character).permit(:name, :campaign_id)
end
```

output: `#<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Tommy"} permitted: true>`

Without require:

```
def character_params
  params.permit(:name, :campaign_id)
end
```

output: `#<ActionController::Parameters {"campaign_id"=>"2366"} permitted: true>`

I might be misunderstanding of what require is actually doing?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not permitting "name"

Comment: The reason why I did not permit "name" is because I wanted the focus to be on "campaign_id". I'll go ahead and edit the post if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`#require` is similar to [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

In Your case You fetch the key `character` and it returns the value of it -> another parameter hash of `{"name"=>"Tommy"}`

To create a `Character` with a reference to a `Campaign` You can implement the controller like this:

```rb
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_campaign

  def create
    @character = @campaign.characters.create(character_params)
    
    ...rest of action
  end

  private

  def load_campaign
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
  end

  def character_params
    params.require(:character).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

A bit of explanation.

1. Use a Rails hook `before_action` to always load the campaign before each action as an instance variable - `@campaign`.
2. In the `#create` method use already loaded `@campaign` to create a new character. Such an approach will automatically assign a reference to the campaign for character if You have properly set up `belongs_to`/`has_many` association between the `Campaign` and the `Character`. Which I assume You do.